# How can I get a Clamp-To-Border effect on an Image-Loaded Texture in THREE.js?

Tags: javascript, html, image-processing, three.js, base64

I have a plane in my scene, with an image loaded onto the texture, and as far as I understand, there is no Clamp-To-Border option for textures, only Clamp-To-Edge, Repeat Wrapping, and Mirrored Wrapping.

Here is an image with the default ClampToEdge effect.

[image]

Here is what I'd like to achieve.
[image]

One solution I could think of would be to add a white border to the image, which would make that whole section white, but I don't know a way to take an image and apply a white border to it.

The image is being loaded via a base64 string, maybe there's a way to add a white border to that string?

Any suggestions greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Can't you load the file in your favorite image editor or an online image editor and expand it's size be 1 pixel more in each direction? Otherwise you can load the image, draw it into a canvas that is 1 size larger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most obvious solution is just to load your image into an image editor, expand it to be 1 pixel larger in each direction and add your border color, save it back out, use that new image with border.

The second most obvious solution is to draw your image into a canvas that is 2 pixels wider and taller.

```
const img = new Image();
img.onload = () => {
  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  canvas.width = img.width + 2;
  canvas.height = img.height + 2;
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.fillStyle = 'white'; // border color
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.drawImage(img, 1, 1);

  // now make a texture using `new THREE.CanvasTexture(canvas)`
};
img.src = urlForImage;
```

Example:

```js
function main() {
  const canvas = document.querySelector('#c');
  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas});

  const fov = 75;
  const aspect = 2;  // the canvas default
  const near = 0.1;
  const far = 5;
  const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);
  camera.position.z = 2;

  const scene = new THREE.Scene();

  const boxWidth = 1;
  const boxHeight = 1;
  const boxDepth = 1;
  const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(boxWidth, boxHeight, boxDepth);

  const cubes = [];  // just an array we can use to rotate the cubes
  
  // create a usable texture to start. We'll update it when the image loads
  const imgCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  const texture = new THREE.CanvasTexture(imgCanvas);
  texture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
  texture.wrapS = THREE.ClampToEdgeWrapping;
  texture.wrapT = THREE.ClampToEdgeWrapping;
  texture.offset.set(-0.5, -0.5);
  texture.repeat.set(2, 2);
  
  const img = new Image();
  img.onload = () => {
    imgCanvas.width = img.width + 2;
    imgCanvas.height = img.height + 2;
    const ctx = imgCanvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.fillStyle = 'white'; // border color
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, imgCanvas.width, imgCanvas.height);
    ctx.drawImage(img, 1, 1);

    texture.needsUpdate = true;    
  };
  img.crossOrigin = 'anonymous'; // only needed if image is from another origin 
  img.src = 'https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/images/wall.jpg';
  
  const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    map: texture, 
  });
  const cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  scene.add(cube);
  cubes.push(cube);  // add to our list of cubes to rotate

  function resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer) {
    const canvas = renderer.domElement;
    const width = canvas.clientWidth;
    const height = canvas.clientHeight;
    const needResize = canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height;
    if (needResize) {
      renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
    }
    return needResize;
  }

  function render(time) {
    time *= 0.001;

    if (resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer)) {
      const canvas = renderer.domElement;
      camera.aspect = canvas.clientWidth / canvas.clientHeight;
      camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    }

    cubes.forEach((cube, ndx) => {
      const speed = .2 + ndx * .1;
      const rot = time * speed;
      cube.rotation.x = rot;
      cube.rotation.y = rot;
    });

    renderer.render(scene, camera);

    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

main();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#c {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r112/build/three.min.js"></script><canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This was exactly what I needed.